# Blender doesnt start up

Tags: linux

Installed linux mint on my macbook pro (13 inch 2010 model)

When I run blender from my terminal this is what it outputs

```
~$ blender
blender: ../src/gallium/state_trackers/dri/dri2.c:698: dri2_allocate_textures: Assertion `*zsbuf' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: That looks like a problem the graphics driver. Does your hardware and OS fulfill the minimum requirements for running Blender 2.8? https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tech specs for your macbook state:

NVIDIA GeForce 320M graphics processor with 256MB of DDR3 SDRAM shared with main memory

So this doesn't meet the minimum memory requirements.  Look slike you need to stick to 2.79 or start saving for a new machine.

Just for completeness, and if you're curious, here are the instructions to check your OpenGL version.  Run the following command from the terminal:

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

If you don't have glxinfo command you can install with

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Make sure that the version is at least OpenGL 3.3.  Even then, the memory constraint is likely to be the problem.  You can always try running blender with the following command:

```
./blender --debug
```

It might offer more information

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply